# How to find the direction of a point with respect to other point by by using longitude and latitude in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my table.

```
Create table City
(
    CityName Nvarchar(250),
    Longitude Float,
    Latitude Float,
    GeoRef Geography
)
```

I want to find the direction of a location(north,south,east,west) with respect to other location by using longitude and latitude or `geography` datatype in SQL Server 2008.I have longitude and latitude of both the locations.

Thanks,
rajbir

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've used the equations from this [website](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

They're pretty easy to implement and you can wrap it into a UDF or sproc. Just remember to watch out for the difference in radians and degrees.